# Why does this program causes a segfault?

Tags: virtual-memory, segmentation-fault

I am currently writing about stack overflows and created the following program below (for reference, I am using a 32-bit linux machine):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
    char foo[16];
    strcpy(foo, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBC");
}
```

This program was compiled with

```
 gcc stack_buffer_2.c -g -o stack_buffer_2 -fno-stack-protector
```

What this program does is:

- fill all "foo" array with 'A' chars
- fill saved EBP with 'B' chars
- write 'C' char (plus null char) to saved ESP

I verified the behavior of this program in GDB andhere is what I got:

```
(gdb) run

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7e30043 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

The program tried to jump to 0xb7e30043 (overflown value, with 0x43 and null terminator) instead of the original value 0xb7e31637, which is a return point from __libc_start_main, in this context.

Here is where things get tricky for me. Doing a "info proc mappings", I see that 0xb7e30043 seems to be like "valid" memory (inside /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)

I am aware that segfaults can be triggered by memory I don't "own", or to unmapped segments. But in this case, since this is inside the memory space from my application, and libc is mapped to it, why I am getting a segfault?

I suspect this is due to some kind of misalignment, since after the overflow EIP is pointing to a random instruction inside libc. If it is, how can I adjust it? What are the constraints behind it, and who enforces it? The kernel, the MMU?

Comment: Unless you haven't loaded the glibc symbols, `0xb7e30043 in ??` seems to imply that you are not inside a `glibc` function. Whatever, why focus on the EIP address? You say nothing about the instruction being executed. Don't think too much on a segfault trace, just `stepi` at the `return` from `main`, watch the registers, examine the assembly code and see what exactly happens. Besides, this question is probably best suited for StackOverflow (no pun intended)

Comment: _0xb7e30043 in ?? seems to imply that you are not inside a glibc function_ - How does the runtime knows I am not inside a glinc function? Does it looks some symbol table before each execution?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the message doesn't say that it is a segfault to access that address, but that executing the code at that address causes a segfault. And this is very likely as you execute a random code without registers set accordingly. Or you have a byte offset to the actual opcode there and get a different opcode getting completely chaotic results. Did you look at the disassembler?

Comment: @Philippos You are right! It is not that I could not jump to it, it that I could and one of the instructions are invalid. I`ll add some details in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the instruction at 0xb7e30043 was invalid.

Here is the current instruction:

```
0xb7e30043: add    %cl,(%eax)
```

I looked into the eax value , and it is zero. From there, things are easier. The process tried to access memory at 0x0 and failed with a segfault.